# How to reverse lookup linux kernel config option in menuconfig

Tags: linux, kernel, config

If I find an option in .config that I would like to enable or disable. Is there a quick way to find it in menuconfig menu?

i.e. I don't want CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM to be set. I had to guess where I can find it in the make menuconfig sub-menu. Is there a programmatic way or a faster way to find the sub-menu, rather than "guess"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can just hit

`/DEVMEM`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

and you'll be taken there? Look for the 'search'/'find' option. If my memory serves me well, it will even tell you about required dependencies

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this BKM, this is incredible useful!

Comment: It won't really take you there but rather show you a list of matching configuration. Your memory serves you well for the required dependencies, it even shows what this config selects :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the key `/` while in menuconfig to research a particular string. This will give you a list of matching configuration option and their path.

You can also use a gui instead of the ncurse menuconfig by typing `make xconfig`.

Another way to do the lookup would be to use the `find` command like that:

```
find /path/to/kernel/sources -name Kconfig -exec grep -Hn config_pattern {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

`.config` is a text file. As such, the easiest way to directly modify an option is to simply place `y`, `m`, or `n` as required. `make oldconfig` can subsequently be used if this leaves the configuration in an inconsistent state.